# How to get Powershell yaml to correctly parse strings that look like dates

Tags: powershell, yaml

I am using powershell v5. $PSVersionTable.PSVersion returns 5.1.19041.906
I am using the powershell-yaml module version 0.4.2 (as indicated by `(get-module -name powershell-yaml).Version`).

When parsing yaml, powershell reads date-like strings as dates. For example ...

```
('Version: !!str 2012-10-17' | ConvertFrom-Yaml).Version.GetType().Name
```

... returns ...

```
DateTime
```

This is extremely wrong. The data has been explicitly tagged string, so it should instead return `String`.

The problem is just as bad in the other direction. For example ...

```
@{Version = '2012-10-17'} | ConvertTo-Yaml
```

... wrongly returns ...

```
Version: 2012-10-17
```

... when the correct answer should be either ...

```
Version: !str 2012-10-17
```

... or ...

```
Version: '2012-10-17'
```

Is there are general case work-around for these bugs?

Comment: You're probably best contacting the authors of that module. Contact details are on Powershell Gallery.